# When to update the external database when using data adapters? To make bulk updates

Tags: c#, datatable, dataadapter

Can anyone clarify when to call the `DataAdapter.Update(datatable)` command? So that we can make bulk updates in the external database. Since, in application where one can update delete and add users if we perform an update in the external database after every action i.e add, delete or update then there would be no use of using data adapters. So, where and when do we call the update command? Since, we have no idea when the application user will quit.
Do we write it in the destruct-or? Does C# have destructor?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why not call Update when the user clicks the save button?

Comment: There is no save button. For example the user can add update or delete employee records. What if he updates and closes the app from the close button on top right.

Comment: Is this a multi-user database?  If so the update command should be done in a function in the database.  With multi-user database you don't want to "check-out an item" and then find the item doesn't exist in database because another user bought the item.

Comment: If the user updates data and closes the form without saving that generally means they don't want to save their changes. Applications generally allow users to save or close without saving.